# How to Graphs in SharePoint Lists using out of the box approach

Tags: sharepoint, list, graph

Is there an approach to display the graphs in the SharePoint lists using out of the box approach and without any customizations etc. I would appreciate any comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have SharePoint Server 2010 Enterprise there is a Chart Part web part which you can point at a SharePoint List and display a graph.

AFAIK this is the only out of the box method, you're looking at third party web parts (or roll your own) to do anything similar.

Comment: So, what if we have SharePoint Server 2007 then? Which options do we have then?

Comment: If you're in 2007 the only option you have is to use third party tools (or to write your own).